# htaccess to only allow 1 ip and forward external users to websites login

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, intranet

I'm not sure if this is possible with using .htaccess but here goes..

We have an externally hosted intranet on Linux/cpanel server. We would like to make it so that when the owner of the intranet is in the office they and anyone else on the office network can access it without any issues via their static IP.

If they are offsite and if anyone else wishes to login they visit www.domain.com/intranet but they are auto forwarded to the intranets login page (site uses concrete5 cms). Once they've logged in they can browse the site..

Or we could do it with once they enter a password they can login perhaps?

Can this be done with htaccess?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: As you have already tagged this question PHP, why not do this in PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess this way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=YOUR_STATIC_IP
RewriteRule index.php$ /redirect_page.php [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect anyone not coming from that static IP to redirect_page.php